# Issues with ToString method in Java LinkedStack implementation

Tags: java, tostring

I am having a slight issue with this assignment:
I am suppose to complete the LinkedStack implementation and ensure peek, isEmpty, and size methods are implemented as defined in the Stack interface.
I believe I gotten most of it working correctly (haven't tested it yet though) but I come across a snag in the ToString method

This was the Instructor's provided startup

```
public interface Stack<T> {
/**
* Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.
* @param element element to be pushed onto the stack
*/
public void push(T element);
/**
 * Removes and returns the top element from this stack.
 * @return the element removed from the stack
 */
public T pop();
/**
 * Returns without removing the top element of this stack.
 * @return the element on top of the stack
 */
public T peek();
/**
* Returns true if this stack contains no elements.
* @return true if the stack is empty
*/
public boolean isEmpty();
/**
* Returns the number of elements in this stack.
* @return the number of elements in the stack
*/
public int size();
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this stack.
 * @return a string representation of the stack
 */
public String toString();}
```

And This is my code for the LinkedStack class:

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements Stack<T> {
private Node head; //the head node
private int size; // number of items


private class Node {
    T item;
    Node next;
}


public LinkedStack() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;

}

public boolean isEmpty() { return (size == 0); }


public T pop() {
    T element = head.item;
    head = head.next;
    size--;

    return element;
}


public void push(T element) {
    Node oldHead = head;
    head = new Node();
    head.item = element;
    head.next = oldHead;
    size++;
}

public int size() { return size; }


public T peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Error: Stack underflow");
    return head.item;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for (T stack : this) {
        string.append(stack + " ");
    }
    return string.toString();
}}
```

From this I get the error
for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    edu.csuniv.isiahjohnson.LinkedStack

Do I need a Iterator object for the stack items or would this only be applicable in a LinkedList class?

Comment: Your stack has to implement `java.lang.Iterable`, as noted in the error message.

Comment: How would Java know how to iterate your stack? You need to implement Iterable, like the message tells you, or you just don't use for-each and instead iterate right there in `toString`. Just use a reference to the current node, start with the head, and iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution. It doesn't implement `Iterable`, but it just iterates the nodes. And I also remove the last space. Instead of `StringBuilder` you could use `StringJoiner`, which exists since Java 8.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  final StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
  Node node = this.head;
  while (node != null) {
    string.append(node.item).append(' ');
    node = node.next;
  }
  // remove last space:
  if (string.length() > 0)
    string.setLength(string.length() - 1);
  return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try something like this and rewrite the main function to not use Iterable since my Instructor didn't really explain this in our lecture notes

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use for each loop in java, your object needs to implement `Iterable` interface.

In java, this code:

```
for (T stack : this) {
   ...
}
```

is a syntactic suger for:

```
for(Iterator<T> iter = this.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    T item = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

so clearly you need `iterator()` to do that, hence- implement `Iterable`